# In EJS template engine, how do I "include" a footer?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, ejs

Let's say I saved a snipplet of a footer. How do I "include" that in my current template?

Comment: You can try <%-include('your-path')%>

Answer (score 94):

I know this question has already been marked as answered, but I believe what you were looking for is the 'partial' syntax. In EJS, you can include the content from one view template in another like so:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Blah blah blah
    <%- partial('footer') %>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Partials are removed from EJS, however you can now use an 'include' syntax. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11835644/175082

Answer (score 56):

EJS makes it very simple to use includes. Here is how it is described in the EJS README:

> Includes are relative to the template with the include statement, for
> example if you have "./views/users.ejs" and "./views/user/show.ejs"
> you would use <%- include('user/show'); %>.
>
> You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

```
<ul>
  <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <%- include('user/show', {user: user}); %>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

So, in your case, if the footer resides in the same directory as the file you want to include it in, you would simply add `<% include('footer') %>` to your file.

Comment: does this work if the footer template is in the parent directory, `<% include ../footer %>`?

Comment: Yes, that will work too. You can use paths to any ejs file on the file system as long as your node process has read access to it.

Comment: Such a weird syntax... to be able to include `../footer` without using quotes or anything.

Comment: This doesn't work without having the path/filename in quotes and parenthesis. EJS docs show <%- include('header'); -%>

Answer (score 22):

the right syntax is `<%- include('<path>', <object with extra parameters>) %>`

include is a function
Includes are relative to the template with the include call. (This requires the 'filename' option.) For example if you have "./views/users.ejs" and "./views/user/show.ejs" you would use <%- include('user/show'); %>.

You'll likely want to use the raw output tag (<%-) with your include to avoid double-escaping the HTML output.

Comment: This is what I was looking for:  whether the included partial view could be provided its own model data.  Do you have a hyperlink to documentation about that?

Comment: I have since found documentation about that here:  https://ejs.co/

Answer (score 19):

You can include the ejs template by

```
<% include includes/header.ejs %>
```

Comment: i don't think that will work you need to use <%- instead <%  to get rendered output  there is different between <%  , <%-  and <%= please read the docs

Comment: I agree with @VikasKandari . The [EJS docs](https://ejs.co/#docs) recommends using the raw output tag `<%-` because it inserts the unescaped value.

Answer (score 12):

In Same DIR
`<%- include('header'); -%>`

Root DIR
`<%- include('../partials/header'); -%>`

Works with EJS v3.0.1

Comment: Its working for me. But why we are using like this ? Is there any reason? If any body knows please share.  Thanks...

Comment: i face backdrop after closing modal using this.

Answer (score 4):

Easy to use include in `ejs` by using this syntax:

`<% include filename %>`

Note: file should be inside views.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax  <% include filename %>  is not working anymore.
<%- include('[relative path]'); %> this syntax works

Answer (score 0):

To include the file, You are supposed to give the relative address from the file calling the include function.
For example, I am assuming that i need to call a file.ejs in my current file.

```
<%- include('file.ejs') -%>
```

if my file.ejs is inside a folder, then:

```
<%- include('folder/file.ejs') -%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have your partials inside a partial directory

Instead of `<% partials/header %>`

Try `<%- include('partials/header') %>`

It works fine for me