# node.js ejs include error

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am creating this template:

```
<% include head %>
<Placemark>
    <name><%=name%></name>
    <description><%=description%></description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates><%=coordinates%></coordinates>
        </Point>
</Placemark>
<% include foot %>
```

But I always get this error:

```
if (!filename) throw new Error('filename option is required for includ
                         ^
```

Directories:

```
justas@justas-Studio-1555:~/node-socket.io/socket.io/examples/kml$ ls -1
app.js
foot.ejs
head.ejs
placemark.ejs
```

Can someone help, I according to toolbox everything should work

app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var fs = require('fs')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});

fs.readFile('placemark.ejs', 'utf8', function (err, template) {

var content = ejs.render(template,{
    name:"test name",
    description:"this is the description",
    coordinates:"-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0"
});

res.write(content);
res.end()
});
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server listening at at xxxxxxxx');
```

using ejs I render template, which constructs from other templates. Using ejs-locals it says that it has no method render.  Is there any way to do this with only 'ejs' ??

Comment: what version of ejs and express are you using? This looks correct and is what I use. https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: /home/justas
├── ejs@0.8.3
├─┬ express@3.0.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a working example:

It appears you need to pass in the filename of the template, in order to be able to use include - See [example here](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/master/examples/functions.js)

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});

fs.readFile('placemark.ejs', 'utf8', function (err, template) {

var content = ejs.render(template,{
    name:"test name",
    description:"this is the description",
    coordinates:"-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0",
    filename: __dirname + '/placemark.ejs'
});

res.write(content);
res.end()
});
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Server listening at at xxxxxxxx');
```

Comment: It does not recognize "partial" 'ReferenceError: ejs:1
 >> 1| <%-partial('head') %>
    2|    <Placemark>
    3|      <name><%=name%></name>
    4|      <description><%=description%></description>

partial is not defined
'

Comment: are you using require('ejs') in your app?

Comment: partial is not supported by latest ejs and express 3. You would need ejs-locals for that.

Comment: Using ejs-locals it says that it has no method render.  Is there any way to do this with only 'ejs' ??

Comment: Thanks for functions example, it did the job :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this error too. I saw alexjamesbrown's answer, but I did not like the solution. I would rather not be including the filename variable for every render; code can become messy! I would prefer to include the file inside the individual views.

So I dug into the ejs lib file and remove the requirement for the filename variable.

You will find the following in \ejs\lib\ejs.js on line 157

```
if (!filename) throw new Error('filename option is required for includes');
```

Simply comment out that line and use `<% include views\include.ejs %>` in your .ejs files to include your individual views.

The above is valid for ejs version 0.8.4

Comment: wow, you are awesome, this is great.  i just added a bug on this on github.   https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/137

Comment: Cheers @JasonS - Just to update this is no longer on line 157. Search for this line in the ejs\lib\ejs.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this question and here's how you can define a template folder and include those templates in your main ejs file:

```
var renderedHtml = ejs.render(content, 
                            {
                                data: data,
                                filename: __dirname + '/app/templates/*'
                            }
                        );
```