# file attachment in AngularJS/NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have problem with include navbar to website. I add ng-include in view:

```
  <body ng-controller="ListProductController" ng-include="navigation()" ng-init="initProducts()">
```

and in controller I have:

```
$scope.navigation = function () {
    if ('$scope.navBar' == 'user') {
        return 'views/admin/share/header.ejs';
    } else {
        return 'views/admin/share/header.ejs';
    }
}
```

Code in header.ejs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
        aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Strona Główna</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/admin/product/list">Produkty</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/category/list">Kategorie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/user/list">Użytkownicy</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if (user != null) { %>
          <li><a href="">Witaj! <%= user.username %></a></li>
          <li><a href="/user/logout">Wyloguj</a></li>
          <% } else { %>
          <li><a href="/user/login">Logowanie</a></li>
          <li><a href="/user/register">Rejestracja</a></li>
           <% } %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And path is :
C:\Users\Turqus\Desktop\node\products\views\admin\share\headers.ejs

Problem is that when i enter on page product/list is nothing, white window.

Comment: Have you initialised your ng-app and are u getting any errors in console?

Comment: No error, in network is : http://localhost:3000/views/admin/share/header.ejs 404 Not Found, there is write Type 'html' maybe it's that he's looking for a .html extension??

Comment: It depends on how your backend is configured. I think its looking for .html extension.

Comment: How to make that he will try to find extension .ejs ???

Comment: I think ur template engine has to compile ur .ejs files to .html

Comment: If I useing in whole project ejs i cant compile to html, then maybe u know, how can I change this appending ??

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813771/in-ejs-template-engine-how-do-i-include-a-footer