# SyntaxError: Unexpected token.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My ejs file path does not work.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '/' in
>   C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\views\landing.ejs
>   while compiling ejs
>
> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
>   https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
>   async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
>       at new Function ()
>       at Template.compile (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:626:12)
>       at Object.compile (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:366:16)
>       at handleCache (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
>       at View.render (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
>       at C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\app.js:43:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\mikda\Desktop\ColtFULL\Section33\YelpCamp\v3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22

Here is my code

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1PNn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uepWN.png)
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN3A9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSGtH.png)
Can somebody solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813771/in-ejs-template-engine-how-do-i-include-a-footer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In EJS template engine, how do I "include" a footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813771/in-ejs-template-engine-how-do-i-include-a-footer)

Answer (score 8):

In your code for `landing.ejs` replace:

```
<%- include ./partials/header %>
```

with this:

```
<%- include ('./partials/header') %>
```

and do the same for the footer also.

Comment: It works. This should be marked as the correct answer.